# How to view html source in Thunderbird when "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"?

Tags: email, thunderbird, source-code, base64, icedove

I press Ctrl+U in the Icedove (Thunderbird), and see plaintext. Last two headers are:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

and the rest data is encoded.

How to conveniently view HTML source of such email in Icedove without manually copying and decoding the base64?

Answer (score 2):

If you search on the Thunderbird Addon page for "[base64](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/search/?q=base64)", you'll find an addon called "[Mnenhy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mnenhy/)" which offers base64-decoding on right-click.

[image: Open The Thunderbird Menu and click on "Add-ons"]
[image: Search for "mnenhy" and install the addon]
[image: Restart the browser]
[image: Right-click on base64-encoded text and click on "Base64" which is as sub-entry of "Decoders"]